# Instructions On How To Recompile The Libgweather Source

Tags: 10.04

I would like to test a patch to correct the weather applet forecast data issue (See  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgweather/+bug/629646) but unsure on how to recompile the libgweather source. Are you able to provide either instructions or URL's on how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware) will get you started quite quickly.

Often, there are just two steps to compiling software from source,

```
./configure
make
```

but much software provides a README file with instructions if there's anything special to be done.

Libgweather also provides an INSTALL file, which has detailed information on how to install once you've compiled it sucessfully.

A patch-file can be applied with

```
patch -p0 < patchfile.patch
```

Comment: Sorry for the long reply. After recompiling the libgweather source with the patch (weather-bom.c.patch), installed the deb package then moving the lib files to the correct directory (From /usr/local/lib to /usr/lib), this resolves the issue :). It would be better if the patch was upstream though. Thank you very much for your help Stefano & others.

Answer (score 3):

Please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToFix.  Quite a few of the Ubuntu developers are available via IRC in the #ubuntu-motu channel, too.  Feel free to ask us for pointers.  Thanks for your interest in helping resolve this bug!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel. Was able to resolve (See below). Will have to look IRC as I've heard about it but never tried it. Hopefully not hard to setup / join. Cheers.